# Convert the month in uppercase in dataframe on strftime that is operated on Index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, strftime

I have a piece of code and a line there converts date in format ddMonYY that is 01Jun19

```
new1 = ((df.index.levels[0] - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')).strftime('%d%b%y') + ' - '+
        df.index.levels[0].strftime('%d%b%y'))
```

This gives output as `01Jun19`

But I want output as `01JUN19` (month uppercase)

I tried using `upper()` as well as `%^b` both did not work

output for upper() is that it is not working on index

```
new1 = ((df.index.levels[0] - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')).strftime('%d%b%y') + ' - '+
        df.index.levels[0].strftime('%d%b%y')).upper()

Error:

   df.index.levels[0].strftime('%d%b%y')).upper()
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Please provide insight on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html) it working same for `index` and for `Series`:

```
df.index.levels[0].strftime('%d%b%y').str.upper()
```

Comment: Yes @jezrael its working i missed the trick there..thank you for highlighting much appreciated